# Array of objects keeps overwriting previous entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a function (`getstudents`) that `prompt()`s a user for input and puts that into the `students` array. The problem I'm having is that every time a new student object is pushed into `students`, the previous object is written over instead of appending it. Anyone know what is happening?

My code:

```
// person object
var person = { firstname: "", lastname: "", email: "" };
function Student(){};
Student.prototype = person;
Student.prototype.sid = "";
Student.prototype.courses = [];
var students = [];




var answer = null;
var k = 0;
function getstudents(answer, students){
    students[k] = new Student();
    students[k].courses = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        if (i < 4) {
            students[k][i] = answer[i];
        }
        if(i > 3) {
            students[k].courses[i-4] = answer[i];
        }
        if(i === answer.length) {

        }

    }
    k++;
}

function getanswer(string) {
    answer = string;
}




function report1() {
    console.log("Report 1 - Registration Information for Students:");
    console.log();
    console.log("Name               Student ID      Email                   CRS#    Fees    Course List");
    console.log("--------           ----------      -------------           -----   ----    -------------");


    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            console.log(students[i][0] + ' ' + students[i][1] + '          ' + students[i][2] + '     ' + students[i][3] + '        ' + students[i].courses.length + '      ' + "$" + feerates[students[i].courses.length] + '    ' + students[i].courses);
          }

}

do {
    getanswer(prompt("Please enter your first name, last name, student ID, email and courses (seperated by ',')"));
    if(answer !== ""){
        var array = answer.split(',');
        answer = array;
        getstudents(answer, students);
    } else {
        answer = null;
    }

} while(answer !== null );

if(answer === "" || answer === null) {
    report1();
} else {
    console.log("No report to write");
}
```

Comment: the first 4 properties are fine, however if you input a different set of courses(the last student property) it overwrites all the other courses elements in the students array. I should have clarified.

Comment: note sure why you said ***the first 4 properties are fine***? `teststudent[0]` won't refer to `teststudent.firstname` (similar for other values of `i`). See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/7xd8cs12/

Comment: It doesn't look the the first 4 properties are fine. It doesn't look like any of this should work at all. But the reason that each student ends up with the same courses is because each student is sharing the same courses array because you have put the courses array on the prototype instead of on the instance - which is why everyone is telling you not to setup your prototype this way.

Comment: Adding `teststudent.courses = [];` after you assign `teststudent` to be `new Student()` would fix your specific problem. But truthfully, this should all be redesigned so as not to use the prototype. The whole point of a prototype is so that objects can share properties, but the sharing is *exactly* what you are reporting as the problem.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. Everything works properly now. I would do it the way Guffa said, but my course teaches JS in a very odd way. I have to do it the way they want it or not at all.

Comment: How can it be working properly if, for example, to access the student's firstname, you have to use student[0], whereas student.firstname will return ''?

Comment: I did notice that issue, So I just used a nested for loop to access the property I needed. dot notation to access an objects property in the array seems to only work with students.courses, but not for the other 4 properties. I'll edit the code to show what it looks like now, but the requirements just want the console.log to display everything properly. I would like to know why I cant use dot notation to access any object property except the courses property though.

Comment: @karsius: `students[0][0] = answer[0];` is very different from `students[0].firstname = answer[0];`. You can't use dot notation to access the firstname because you are not storing the firstname value to student.firstname, you are storing it to student[0].

Comment: @karsius: Also, if your course cares only if the code works, and does no evaluation of the design/implementation, then I think this course is doing you (and the discipline of programming) a disservice.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is? isnt student[0] accessing student.firstname?

Comment: @karsius: No. Your students are object instances. Objects are collections of key/value pairs. Accessing an object's value at key 0 is not the same as accessing its value at key 'firstname'. You will probably benefit from reading more about objects in JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the student that is overwritten when you push a new student, it's the information in the object that is overwritten when you populate the student object earlier in the code.

As you have put the properties of the student in the prototype, all students share a single set of properties. When you set the first name of a student, you set the first name for all students, because the property is in the prototype which is the same for all student objects.

Create properties for the student in the instance of the student instead of putting them in the prototype:

```
function Student(){
  this.firstname = '';
  this.lastname = '';
  this.email = '';
  this.sid  = '';
  this.courses = [];
}

var students = [];

...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep the prototypes as is. It's part of the requirements for my code.

Comment: @karsius: Then you can just ignore the useless properties from the prototype and create new ones with different names. You can add properties to the object after it is created.

Comment: @karsius: If the requirements stipulate bad code then the requirements need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows that you're struggling with the concept of prototypes in JS. The issue is that each student you are creating is empty. But each student refers to a single object for their actual data (the prototype). When you "change" a student, all you're doing is changing the prototype which every instance of a student shares.

Instead of changing a student you change what a student inherits from. The solution is to include all the data inside the function that makes a student. There each student is given data when you use the `this` keyword.

Whenever JS cannot find a property on an object, it searches another object (if it exists). If it cannot find the property on that object it searches another. Inheritance works in JS, because there's a way to specify what object JS will use if it cannot find a property. You can create 10 instances of a person, that all share 1 object. Although the 10 share the properties on the one, they do not each have there own data, which is your error above.

Technically speaking, any function object which sets a `prototype` property on an object will allow all objects created from the function to share the object's properties. Hope that helps.